# Как переместить файлы по дате в другую папку

Tags: powershell

Нужен скрипт PowerShell, который проверяет файлы в исходной папке и файлы, у которых дата изменения старше заданной в скрипте, переносит эти файлы в определенную сетевую папку.
Сделал такой код, выдаёт ошибку связанную с LastWriteTime.
Помогите исправить её.

```
$TargetFolder = "C:\PSTESTDEL" 
$Period = "-5" 
$CurrentDay = Get-Date
$ChDaysDel = $CurrentDay.AddMinutes($Period)
$DestPath = "C:\PSTESTREPLACE"
 
dir $TargetFolder | where LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5) | cp -Destination "C:\PSTESTREPLACE"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$TargetFolder = "C:\PSTESTDEL"
$DestPath = "C:\PSTESTREPLACE"
$ChDaysDel = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)

Get-childitem -Path $TargetFolder -recurse | where-object {$_.lastwritetime -lt ($ChDaysDel) -and -not $_.PSIsContainer} | mv -Destination $DestPath
```

Удалил лишние, на мой взгляд, переменные, а также дублирование расчета дат.
Заменил `cp` на `mv`, потому что было копирование, а в задании написано - перенос.
Подсматривал [здесь](https://shellgeek.com/get-childitem-lastwritetime/)